# Glassfish Server Webservice behind Apache HTTP Server

Tags: java, apache, jsf

Hi 
We started to create our applications with J2EE. We now created a Webservice and deployed it to the Glassfish Server. We have written an apache proxy rule to access it via **https://our.server.com/webservice-war** (only https port is open to that server):

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /webservice-war http://our.server.com:8080/webservice-war
ProxyPassReverse /webservice-war http://our.server.com:8080/webservice-war
```

Now everything works fine, but when we go to the to the ServiceEndpoint page (which is automatically generated) there is a link to the WSDL page:
**http://our.server.com:8080/webservice-war/HostaliasSearchImplService?wsdl**

which is obously wrong (Glassfish listens to port 8080). and also https is changed to http

Anyone an idea how I can fix it, that the automatically generated link is:

**https://our.server.com/webservice-war/HostaliasSearchImplService?wsdl**

BR, Rene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution!

Anonym gave me a good hint about mod_jk. So here the complete configuration (for RHEL5).

First of all Download the mod_jk module for apache: http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/binaries/linux/jk-1.2.31/x86_64/

Put in in the modules directory /etc/httpd/modules and make it executeable:

```
chmod +x mod_jk-1.2.31-httpd-2.2.x.so
```

After that create /etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties:

```
# Define 1 real worker using ajp13
worker.list=worker1
# Set properties for worker1 (ajp13)
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009
```

The Port 8009 is the where the Glassfish jk connector listens (we come to that later).

No we have to configure mod_jk, therefore create the file: /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_jk.conf with the following content:

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk-1.2.31-httpd-2.2.x.so
JkWorkersFile /etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties
# Where to put jk logs
JkLogFile /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log
# Set the jk log level [debug/error/info]
JkLogLevel debug
# Select the log format
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
# JkOptions indicate to send SSL KEY SIZE,
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
# JkRequestLogFormat set the request format
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
# Send everything for context /atsi-war to worker named worker1 (ajp13)
JkMount /yourapp-war/* worker1
```

(This means everything from your http://apache.webserver.com/yourapp-war/ will bi redirected to Glassfish yourapp-war application context)

Important, if you are using virtual hosts on apache, you have to set the option:
    JkMountCopy On
for your virtual servers. Explication:

> If this directive is set to "On" in
>   some virtual server, the mounts from
>   the global server will be copied to
>   this virtual server, more precisely
>   all mounts defined by JkMount or
>   JkUnMount.

Now we have to create the jk connecter in glassfish:

```
asadmin create-http-listener --listenerport 8009 --listeneraddress 0.0.0.0 --defaultvs server jk-connector
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.network-listeners.network-listener.jk-connector.jk-enabled=true
```

Restart Glassfish, and everything sould work.

Answer (score 4):

I discovered what I consider to be a very simple and elegant way to deal with the issue:  use mod_substitute.  Since those of us with this problem are already using Apache, and it's built in and simple, I liked this approach best.

I put a block similar to the below in one of my Apache conf files and found joy:

```
<Location />
   AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/xml
   Substitute "s|http://internal:8080/foo|https://external/foo|ni"
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

As for rewriting the https -> http, I'm not sure that's possible(yet) without using mod_jk, see [here](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/glassfish-behind-https-reverse-proxy)
, but see also this [little guide](http://www.manorrock.com/documents/glassfish/proxy-ssl.html)

Though, generally, you'll need configure Glassfish and set http.proxyPort (and probably http.proxyHost too). Hopefully that should reflect in the autogenerated WSDL URL.

Here's 3 different ways to do this:

**1**
Use asadmin (in the Glassfish bin/ directory, run

```
asadmin create-jvm-options "-Dhttp.proxyPort=80"
asadmin create-jvm-options "-Dhttp.proxyHost=our.server.com"
```

**2** 
Edit domain.xml and add under the `<java-config>` element

```
 <jvm-options>-Dhttp.proxyPort=80</jvm-options>
 <jvm-options>-Dhttp.proxyHost=our.server.com</jvm-options>
```

**3.** 
Open the Glassfish admin web page, under Application Server -> VM Settings -> JVM Options and add these options

```
http.proxyPort=80
http.proxyHost=our.server.com
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not solve the problem. Still the wrong link. Maybe I can create a rewrite rule on glassfish. Don't know yet.

Answer (score 0):

Setting

```
server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.server-name=MyHost:80
```

on GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)  solved problem to me.